# Grails screen appears blank - no error on console

Tags: grails

The Grails system with which we've been working with fine for several months, now has a problem whereby the /login/auth page appears blank.  The problem with the build only occurs on a deployed Tomcat system, and not on local development machines, where it works fine.  There is no error appearing on the console at all.    The Network tab in Chrome shows a 404 error.  We've put console debug messages in the auth() method within LoginController and these are not showing up.  Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: some code and stack traces would definitely not harm :)

Comment: Yes - got it thanks- we added a stacktrace for the deployed system (not done that before).  We discovered an error to do with a file naming.  What's odd is why the error didn't appear in the console log.   This problem has nothing to do with Spring Security...